# The collection of the armeture and model has an error

Tags: rigging, collections

When I make the collection of my rigged model invisible, only the armature goes invisible and the model is still visible. the collection has the icon of the armeture. But since the model is now in the collection, shouldn't the model also go invisible when the collection isn't invisible?

Did I do something wrong while parenting the armature and model?

[image]

Comment: you have 2 characters and 2 armature, and non of them are in a collection, have share the good file?

Comment: The "collection" with the armature symbol is not a collection, it is the armature. That the model is shown below in the hierarchy means that it is parented to the armature. Disabling the visibility is to be set individually in the _Outliner_ or with all selected by pressing H in the _3D Viewport_ or you you have to Alt + click on _Show In_ > _Viewport/Renders_ under _Object Properties_ > _Visibility_.